# How to test a ClassFileTransformer / javaagent?

Tags: java, instrumentation, javaagents

I implemented a `ClassFileTransformer` for a javaagent using ASM. Because it has some bugs, I want to write a JUnit test case for it. How do I do this?

Using pseudo-code I thought along the lines:

```
// Have a test class as subject
public static class Subject {
  public void doSomething(){...}
}
// Manually load and transform the subject
...?
// Normally execute some now transformed methods of the subject
new Subject().doSomething();
// Check the result of the call (i.e. whether the correct attached methods were called)
Assert.assertTrue(MyClassFileTransformer.wasCalled());
```

Now the question is: How do I manually load and transform the subject and make the JVM/Classloader use my manipulated version of it? Or do I completely miss something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I got it. One needs to implement an own `ClassLoader` that does the same transformation with the test subject as the `ClassFileTransformer` (e.g. calls it). And of course the subject class may not already be loaded, so there may not be any direct usage of it. So I used Java reflection API to execute the methods of the subject class.

In a separate file:

```
public static class Subject {
    public void doSomething(){...}
}
```

In the test:

```
private static class TransformingClassLoader extends ClassLoader {

    private final String className;

    public TransformingClassLoader(String className) {
        super();
        this.className = className;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> loadClass(String name) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        if (name.equals(className)) {
            byte[] byteBuffer = instrumentByteCode(fullyQualifiedSubjectClass);
            return defineClass(className, byteBuffer, 0, byteBuffer.length);
        }
        return super.loadClass(name);
    }
}

@Test
public void testSubject(){
    ClassLoader classLoader = new TransformingClassLoader(fullyQualifiedSubjectClass);
    Class<?> subjectClass = classLoader.loadClass(fullyQualifiedSubjectClass);
    Constructor<?> constructor = subjectClass.getConstructor();
    Object subject = constructor.newInstance();
    Method doSomething = subjectClass.getMethod("doSomething");
    doSomething.invoke(subject);
    Assert.assertTrue(MyClassFileTransformer.wasCalled());
}
```